# how to declare UIView globally in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

Unable to create View globally. My code is :

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
 {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }   

 // CODING
 class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    //Unable to create View globally, kindly help me,, 
    //Error coming like this

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) 
    {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }   

    var view11:UIView
    var img_view11:UIImageView
    .
    .
    .

    @IBAction func long(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) 
    {
        var data1: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img.image)
        view11 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
        img_view11 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
        img_view11.image = UIImage(data: data1)
        view11.addSubview(img_view11)
        self.vw.addSubview(view11)
    }
 }
```

If we erase that "required" line, we get this error:

`"fix-it Insert \n required initializer.`"

after that, if we run, then the thread error is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside the class do:

```
var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
```

Then you will be able to use it globally

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the error by replacing the `fatalError` code with `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`.

This initialization is required for objects that are initialized from a nib (or storyboard), I believe.